# Notepad++ file freezes

Tags: batch, notepad++

I have a very small batch file containing `psexec` commands (30 lines of code), however, when I try to open this file in Notepad++, it takes a really long to time open and when I modify something in the file, it freezes when I click the save button.

What could be the reason for this, as Notepad++ is fine with any other batch file?

Comment: Failing hard disk? Corrupted notepad++

Comment: Which version of Notepad++? Does the same happen when you edit in regular Notepad.exe?

Comment: Hard disk is fine. This issue occurs on different systems either.

Comment: Does this occur when  you open with another text editor?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, regular notepad is also freezing while opening

Comment: Could you show us the content of the file?

Comment: I cannot share the content unfortunately. But, as I wrote, it is series of PsExec commands.

Comment: @qwers If you `echo` or `type` the contents of the file to a new file, does the same issue occur?

Comment: Is the file local or on a remote machine? Is is a link that maybe uses a Start In path that is remote or not available?